# Foreach -Parrallel no output returned n Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

This might sound like a silly question, but when I run the following command in Powershell 7, using the -Parallel switch, the command doesn't show the expected output, when I remove the -Parallel switch I get the expected output.

The test.ps1 file is:

```
Get-Date
$hostname = hostname
Write-Host "$hostname"
```

The -Parallel command:

```
(Measure-Command {$comps = Get-Content C:\temp\vms.txt | foreach -Parallel {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -FilePath {C:\temp\test.ps1} -Verbose}}).Seconds
```

The working command:

```
(Measure-Command {$comps = Get-Content C:\temp\vms.txt | foreach {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -FilePath {C:\temp\test.ps1} -Verbose}}).Seconds
```

When I run the working command I get the output below, although I still don't get the `Get-Date` output

Hostname1
Hostname2
Hostname3

I want to run commands to several VMs with a `Catch` so if the operation fails I get some information back.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: foreach parallel does work in a seperate session, so its totally diffrent from the current session

Comment: @user3898488 Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$comps = Get-Content C:\temp\vms.txt 
invoke-command -ComputerName $comps -FilePath C:\temp\test.ps1
```

Invoke-command already runs in parallel.